# What are the semantics of "strict returns"?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

In the [Haskell Performance Resource](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance) wiki-section, the not further explained recommendation is given to

> - Use strict returns (`return $! ...`) unless you absolutely need them lazy.

Why is that a good thing to do? When exactly is the `...`-expression (Whnf-)forced?

Given the "Left identity" monad-law and the definition

```
f $! x = x `seq` f x
```

I can rewrite (in `do`-notation`):

```
do x' <- return $! x
   f x'
```

to

```
do x' <- x `seq` return x
   f x'
```

But it seems I can't get to

```
do f $! x
```

PS: If the `BangPatterns`-extension is available, is

```
do !x' <- return x
   f x'
```

semantically the same as the first `do`-expression given above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a reason you can't get from

```
do x' <- x `seq` return x
   f x'
```

to

```
f $! x
```

It's because they are not the same.  Just expand the do notation:

```
(x `seq` return x) >>= (\ x' -> f x')
```

The `seq` will only be evaluated if the `(>>=)` is strict in its first argument.  That's not necessarily true.

Comment: I see... but what does this say about the usefulness of `return $! ...`? Does it only make sense for strict monads?

Comment: @hvr: If the monad is strict in it's return-type, then yes. The construct is especially useful, for monads where you usually want to evaluate a side-effect of the monad and not the monad itself.

Comment: It makes sense for the final thing in a do block to be `return $! ...` because the return value of a (called) function is always evaluated.  I.e., in `... >>= \ x -> return $! ...`, once that lambda expression is called it's going to evaluate the `($!)` application.

Comment: By "lambda expression is called" do you mean only the outer beta-reduction, or rather forcing the whole lambda-application to be evaluated to WHNF (which in this case could only be triggered by a `>>=`/`>>` operation?)?

Comment: @hvr I mean the point when ((\ x -> ...) arg) is evaluated to WHNF.  When this happens depends on which monad this is.

Answer (score 1):

For IO there is also the useful [Control.Exception.evaluate](http://file:///Library/Haskell/ghc-7.0.2/doc/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Control-Exception.html#v%3aevaluate):

> Forces its argument to be evaluated to
>   weak head normal form when the
>   resultant IO action is executed. It
>   can be used to order evaluation with
>   respect to other IO operations; its
>   semantics are given by

```
evaluate :: a -> IO a
evaluate x = (return $! x) >>= return
```